# How can I create an image slideshow with embedded links for my blog?

Tags: html, slideshow, blogger

I am very, very, very new to programming... I honestly know just about nothing. The past month or so I've been working on improving my blog and have been using alot of HTML coding for it, so I'm sort of beginning to understand a little of it.

Either way, I've done alot of basic stuff that I was able to easily find online... Mostly codes that were provided to me that I just needed to plug links into. I also started playing with changing the color and size of some things by altering the code.

My current project is that I want to create a slideshow for my blog that will be in my sidebar. Currently I have buttons of the blogs I follow or support on my page... But there are too many and it looks very busy. I would like to put all of these buttons in a slideshow, but still make it so that people are redirected to those other bloggers when they click on those images. Can someone please walk me through step by step how to do this? If you already have a code to provide that I can use to just plug in the embedded link codes I already have that would be great! It needs to be about 240 wide.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Most good slideshow libraries allow you to wrap the image in a link. I mainly use [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) and the html would look something like this.

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <a href="url"><img src="image" alt="alt"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="url"><img src="image" alt="alt"></a>
        </li>
        etc...
    </ul>
</div>
```

With flexslider (as with many good slideshows), the content of your `<li>` can be almost anything, just try to keep them a similar height.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in a good direction :) Hopefully I will be able to figure this out!